# Are Markov Random Fields and Conditional Random Fields still used in computer vision?

Tags: computer-vision, state-of-the-art, conditional-random-field

Back before deep learning, there were a lot of different attempts at computer vision. Some involved Conditional Random Fields and Markov Random Fields, which were both computationally difficult and hard to understand/implement.

Are these areas still being developed in the computer vision domain? What was the end result of this line of study? I haven't seen any papers on this topic be cited in top-performing benchmarks, so I assume nobody cares about them anymore, but I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1):

In the [**Image-to-Image Translation with Conditional Adversarial Networks**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07004) paper (popularly known as *pix2pix*), they used a Markovian Discriminator to effectively model the image as a Markovian Random Field.

There were some papers in the last 5 years concerning Markov Fields. Here are some of them:-

1. [Combining Markov Random Fields and Convolutional Neural Networks for Image Synthesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04589)
2. [Precomputed Real-Time Texture Synthesis with Markovian Generative Adversarial Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.04382)